# Crashlytics open multiple browser tabs during compilation of iOS project

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

During compilation of iOS project with Crashlytics added via pods 2-6 tabs open:

```
https://fabric.io/organization/ios/apps/bundle/issues?time=last-seven-days&event_type=crash&subFilter=state&state=open
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem.
In my case, the Fabric.app was running (or I thought it was) but actually it was stuck, not responding.
After I terminated the app, I could compile again without having a new tab opened in Safari every time.

Maybe that helps :)